# How can I write a python function to accept *arguments and a keyword argument?

Tags: python

I feel like there must be something simple I'm missing here.
Here's what I want to do:

```
>>> def x(*args, a=False):
...   print args, a

>>> x(1,2)
(1,2) False

>>> x(1,2,3, a=True)
(1,2,3) True
```

But you can't define a function like that.

I know this would work, but it doesn't seem as nice:

```
>>> def x(*args, **kwargs):
...   if 'a' in kwargs:
...       a = kwargs['a']
...   else
...       a = False
...   print args, a
```

What's the best way to do this?
I'm using python 2.6

Comment: I know you're using 2.6, but if this is a simple script, I wonder if it might be possible to move it to 3.0. I just tested your exact code in 3.2 and it works perfectly (probably due to Py3's notion of 'head' and 'tail', which is pretty awesome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you have is the only way. But you can write it nicer:

```
def x(*args, **kwargs):
    a = kwargs.get('a', False)
    print args, a

x(1,2,3,a=42)
```

Comment: I may have exaggerated how ugly the alternative was :p

Comment: You may want to add something like `assert 'a' in kwargs, "a is required"` or `if 'a' not in kwargs: raise TypeError("x takes one keyword argument, none given")` to help debug problems.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/

> The first change is to allow regular
>   arguments to appear after a varargs
>   argument:
>
> ```
> def sortwords(*wordlist, case_sensitive=False):
>    ...
> ```
>
> This function accepts any number of
>   positional arguments, and it also
>   accepts a keyword option called
>   'case_sensitive'.

So it's coming in Python 3

Comment: FWIW, Python 3 is here if you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well all *args really is a variable list of arguments and all **kwargs really is a dictionary keyword-only arguments.

Unless I am misunderstanding, why not just do this?

```
def x(args, a=False):
    print args, a

x((1,2),True) #<- just passes in a list instead of special list and dict

output
(1,2) True

x((1,2))

output
(1,2) False
```

It is not as pythonic without the variable *argument list and detection of the **kwargs keyword-only arguments dict but probably works for your needs.

Comment: That's the best solution I thought of, but was hoping for something nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You either must take your second choice, OR you must re-order the arguments so the argument with default comes first:

```
def x(a=False, *args):
```

Comment: Considered that, but I'd have to call `x(False, 1,2,3)` rather than just `x(1,2,3)` in which case it might as well be `def x(a, *args):`